# Create new column with substring from another pandas column if substring is in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a new column from a value in a list if the value is in another column - see example below:

```
state_us = ['Ohio', 'California']
fake_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['Route 66, Ohio, US', 'California US']), columns = ['Address'])
#               Address
# 0  Route 66, Ohio, US
# 1       California US

results_df = pd.DataFrame({'Address': ['Route 66, Ohio, US', 'California US'], 'State': ['Ohio', 'California']})
#               Address       State
# 0  Route 66, Ohio, US        Ohio
# 1       California US  California
```

this is my not so successful attempt

```
fake_df['State'] = fake_df['Address'].apply(lambda x: element for element in state_us if element in x else np.nan)
```

Comment: I think u mixed ur results_df. Shouldn't it be like this: pd.DataFrame(data={'Address': ['Route 66, Ohio, US', 'California US'], 'State': ['Ohio', 'California']})

Comment: correct! got any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the state patterns from the addresses:

```py
pattern = '|'.join(state_us)
fake_df['State'] = fake_df['Address'].str.extract(rf'({pattern})')

#               Address       State
# 0  Route 66, Ohio, US        Ohio
# 1       California US  California
```